# Connect-Rest not handling requests

Tags: node.js, rest, express, connect

I have this code in my app.js file to handle api requests

```
app.use('/api', cors());
rest.get('/posts', function(req, content, cb) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts) {
    if (err) return cb({error: 'Internal error.'});
    cb(null, posts.map(function(p) {
      return {
        title: p.title
      };
    }));
  });
});

var apiOptions = {
  context: '/api',
  domain: require('domain').create(),
};

apiOptions.domain.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('API domain error.\n', err.stack);
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Server shutting down after API domain error.');
    process.exit(1);
  }, 5000);
  server.close();
});

app.use(rest.rester(apiOptions));
```

When I make a get request to `http://localhost:3000/api/posts` I get this info message

```
info: Request won't be handled by connect-rest
```

And then after is some errors about not finding views because I haven't made any views yet. How can I get connect-rest to handle these requests?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by moving the line `app.use(rest.rester(apiOptions));` above the line where the first API method is defined (first usage of`rest.get(...)`).